# Problem with image() object

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

Look at this script please

```
var src="some.jpg";
var img = new Image(); 
    img.src = src;
    img.id = "crop_image";
    $("#crop_image").load(function()
    {
     $("#crop_cont").append(img);
    })
```

why in my `.load` function i can't access to img element?

Thanks much

UPDATE:

But the following works

```
$('<img src="'+src+'" />').load(function()
                {
                    var img = new Image(); 
                    img.src = src;
                    $("#crop_cont").append(img);
                })
```

Comment: yes without providing DOM structure how can it display..see  my answer too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of those two examples really make any sense.

In the first, you create an Image but you don't add it to the DOM. Thus, when you ask jQuery to go find it, it can't because it's not there yet.

In the second, you create a new image tag, which (internally) is going to give jQuery an actual DOM element to work with. However, that call to append your Image object to the DOM seems superfluous.  You've already *got* an `<img>` so there's no need for another one.

I'd change the second one as follows:

```
    $('<img src="'+src+'" />').load(function()  {
      $("#crop_cont").append(this);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

`$("#crop_image")` will not find your new image because you haven't added it to the DOM yet. Use `$(img)` instead.

A correct way to do it would be:

```
var src="some.jpg";
var img = new Image(); 
img.src = src;
img.id = "crop_image";
$(img).load(function(){
     $("#crop_cont").append(this);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`#crop_image`, does it actually get appended to the doc? if so when?

Answer (score 0):

you need to provide html to that.right

```
<img src="" />
```

Otherwise how can it display

Answer (score 0):

image has it's own onload event, it's probably easiest to do something like this

```
var src="some.jpg";
var img = new Image();

img.id = "crop_image"; 
img.onload = $("#crop_cont").append(img); // event added
img.src = src;
```

edit: err, I mean the Image Object.